Algebraic closure in elementary extensions and Diophantine definability of rings of integers
Let $K$ be a number field, and $O_K$ its ring of integers. Consider models $K'$ and $K''$ of the theory of $K$ such that $K' \subseteq K''$.
Is it true that if $O_K$ is diophantine in $K$, then $K'$ must be algebraically closed in $K''$ for all such extensions?
By $O_K$ is diophantine in $K$, we mean that $O_K$ is existentially definable in $K$. Also algebraically closed is meant in the model-theoretic sense: $K'$ is algebraically closed in $K''$ if every element of $K''$ satisfying a polynomial equation with coefficients in $K'$ is already in $K'$.

I presume "algebraically closed" here is meant in the model-theoretic, as opposed to field-theoretic, sense? Separately, I don't see the connection implied by your question; can you explain why such an implication might hold (I may be missing something obvious)?

It says "in the model-theoretic sense", but the definition given is the one for algebraic in the algebraic sense. In that sense the conclusion is known (without having to assume anything on $O_K$) by Philip Dittmann's "Irreducibility of polynomials over global fields is diophantine" https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07829
